# How do you put a string variable in the confirm() function in Javascript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to confirm with the user if the following string he or she is about to enter is correct but the confirmation box won't appear. Here is that segment of the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<script>
   function validateForm(){
      var pkey = document.forms["createProductForm"]["pagekeyTF"].value;
      var agree = confirm("Is this your product?\n\n ${pkey}");

      if(agree) //Do something
      else //Do something else
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="createProductForm" controller="actions" action="ImplementNewProduct" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

      <g:textField id="productTF" name="productTF" value="My Product" />       
      <button id="createProductID" name="createButton" value="Create Product">Create Product</button>

   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I not allowed to pass in string variables in the confirmation function? Because if I take off the `${pkey}` it works fine but it does not include the user's input and that is not what I am not trying to achieve. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: clearly I could of also put 
`var agree = confirm("Is this your product?\n\n" + pkey);` 
If you guys aren't familiar with gstrings from groovy.

Comment: Oh and I put `value="My Product"` inside the textfield for testing purposes so that way I can always get a value back.

Comment: You need to check the error console of the browser (Ctrl+Shift+J) to see if any js error occurred. Also check the _rendered html_ (right click, view sourcE).

Comment: Why don't people google before they ask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit it like this :

```
var pkey = document.forms["createPixelForm"]["pagekeyTF"].value;
var agree = confirm("Is this your product?\n\n " + pkey);
```

Comment: I tried this before but it did not work. I must of not saved it or something but now it works! I did not know you can check for js errors so that also definitely helped too. Thank you ahmed and @mshsayem

Comment: yw at any time Eli :D